# Unable parse using simple XML for android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, simple-framework

I am trying to parse the following xml using simple xml for android. The xml looks simple but i am unable to parse it. Can anyone please help me by providing the model classes needed for parsing this xml. Thanks in advance.

```
<letters>
  <letter linkable="true">A</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">B</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">C</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">D</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">E</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">F</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">G</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">H</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">I</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">J</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">K</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">L</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">M</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">N</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">O</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">P</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">Q</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">R</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">S</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">T</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">U</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">V</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">W</letter>
  <letter linkable="false">X</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">Y</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">Z</letter>
  <letter linkable="true">123</letter>
</letters>
```

Comment: did you try to parse ??

Comment: yes. But since the model classes were wrong, i am always getting null pointer

Comment: please visit http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm

Comment: did you use sax for this ??

Comment: No. The application is using simple xml framework for parsing. I have parsed several other xmls using this. But no luck with this xml

Comment: can you show your parsing cose with logcat here ..

Comment: log cat have no errors reported sicne i have given strict mode = false

Comment: post your code what have you tried.

Answer (score 2):

***Simple*** is exactly what can help you here: deserialize your xml into java objects.

And here's how to do this:

### Class `Letters`

```
public class Letters
{
    @ElementList(name = "letters", inline = true)
    private List<Letter> letters;

    // ...
}
```

### Class `Letter`

```
@Root(name = "letter")
public class Letter
{
    @Attribute(name = "linkable")
    private boolean linkable;
    @Text
    private String letter;

    // ...
}
```

### How to use

```
Serializer ser = new Persister();
Letters l = ser.read(Letters.class, xml); // xml is your input source; a string, file, stream, whatever ...
```

Now, your xml is fully deserialized to java objects. Btw. those can contain further methods / fields. Serializing a `Lists` object back to xml is possible too: just replace `ser.read(...)` with `ser.write(...)`.